# How to get the list of my friends in a city using the graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to use the graph API to get the list of friends in New York city as the hometown or checkins. Can someone please help me with this one.

Comment: me/friends?fields=location,hometown,name but this gives me all my friends with their hometown. I dont know how to filter it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get all the details, simply filter the result with if condition on hometown.

If you don't want to filter at your end, you could simply use fql

> SELECT uid, name, hometown_location FROM user WHERE uid IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() ) AND hometown_location.city ="New York"

The location parameters on which you can filter your search-

```
hometown_location.city 
hometown_location.state
hometown_location.country
hometown_location.name
```

If you havent use fql yet, you can take a look [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/).

Comment: 1. The FQL is not returning any data 
2. How do I use the fileter in graph API ? In this query me/friends?fields=location,hometown,name    where should I add the filter ? I am very new to this API and would appreciate your help

Comment: The FQL worked, thanks!